# When trying to run cordapp-example I get multiple errors

Tags: corda

I'm trying to run the cordapp-example in IntelliJ IDEA.  I select Run Example Cordapp - Kotlin using module cordapp-example.workflows-kotlin.test.  When I start the app I get an error listed below for each node its trying to start.

[INFO] 15:06:56,786 [driver-pool-thread-0] network.NodeInfoFilesCopier. - Now watching: F:\Downloads\samples\cordapp-example\build\node-driver\20190809-200647.418\NotaryService
[INFO] 15:06:57,204 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Starting out-of-process Node Notary Service, debug port is not enabled
[INFO] 15:07:20,826 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.RPCClient. - Startup took 3684 msec
[INFO] 15:07:21,014 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Node handle is ready. NodeInfo: NodeInfo(addresses=[localhost:10000], legalIdentitiesAndCerts=[O=Notary Service, L=Zurich, C=CH], platformVersion=4, serial=1565381232630), WebAddress: localhost:10003
[INFO] 15:07:21,099 [main] network.NodeInfoFilesCopier. - Now watching: F:\Downloads\samples\cordapp-example\build\node-driver\20190809-200647.418\PartyA
[INFO] 15:07:21,102 [main] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Starting out-of-process Node PartyA, debug port is not enabled
[INFO] 15:07:21,161 [main] network.NodeInfoFilesCopier. - Now watching: F:\Downloads\samples\cordapp-example\build\node-driver\20190809-200647.418\PartyB
[INFO] 15:07:21,164 [main] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Starting out-of-process Node PartyB, debug port is not enabled
[INFO] 15:07:21,214 [main] network.NodeInfoFilesCopier. - Now watching: F:\Downloads\samples\cordapp-example\build\node-driver\20190809-200647.418\PartyC
[INFO] 15:07:21,217 [main] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Starting out-of-process Node PartyC, debug port is not enabled
[INFO] 15:08:14,987 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.RPCClient. - Failed Startup took 1055 msec
[INFO] 15:08:14,987 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.RPCClient. - Failed Startup took 1054 msec
[INFO] 15:08:14,987 [driver-pool-thread-0] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Exception while connecting to RPC, retrying to connect at localhost:10013
 net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:218) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:93) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:32) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:193) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:183) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:72) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:392) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:375) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:344) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:170) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:79) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt$poll$task$1.run(InternalTestUtils.kt:206) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:797) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:216) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    ... 18 more
[INFO] 15:08:14,987 [driver-pool-thread-1] internal.DriverDSLImpl. - Exception while connecting to RPC, retrying to connect at localhost:10005
 net.corda.client.rpc.RPCException: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:218) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:93) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:32) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:193) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtils.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:183) ~[corda-core-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:72) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:392) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:375) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:344) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:170) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.DriverDSLImpl$establishRpc$connectionFuture$1.invoke(DriverDSLImpl.kt:79) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.testing.node.internal.InternalTestUtilsKt$poll$task$1.run(InternalTestUtils.kt:206) ~[corda-node-driver-4.0.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_221]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_221]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119007: Cannot connect to server(s). Tried with all available servers.
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:797) ~[artemis-core-client-2.6.2.jar:2.6.2]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:216) ~[corda-rpc-4.0.jar:?]

Comment: I using java jdk 1.8.0_221.

Answer (score 1):

Please check whether config.rpc.host and config.rpc.port are configured correctly in "application.properties" file.